# Map the PHP date format into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a Unix timestamp to time in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript)

I have been storing the user's date format preference in the database as a string of the format used by PHP's date() function.

A need has arisen for dates to be calculated by Javascript. Is anyone aware of some sort of mapping of the PHP format into Javascript?

From passing the PHP date format `Ymd` string to a Javascript function I would expect it to return `20010310`

Comment: You just feeling lazy today? Don't want to google it?? :-)

Comment: And what would TODAYs date look like? Try `var server time = new Date(<?php echo time()*1000; ?>)`

Comment: -1 for not doing *any basic* research

Comment: I actually spent 3 hours researching, bad luck I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you want this:
http://phpjs.org/functions/date/

though i would strongly recommend you to use this:
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: In case you want to use the PHP formats: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30186611/php-dateformat-to-moment-js-format

Answer (score 2):

**PHP:**

```
$myDate = date('Ymd');
```

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($myDate); ?> * 1000);
</script>
```